# Load error when I run `ruby2.0 program.rb` which calls watir-webdriver

Tags: php, ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

When I run `system('ruby /lib/program.rb')` within a PHP script, I get this in my `error.log` file:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)
```

And when I change to `system('ruby2.0 /lib/program.rb')`, I get this:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver (LoadError)
```

When I run `ruby /lib/program.rb`, it works in terminal. Why is it different when called via PHP's `system` function?

The PHP file is in my public folder. The Ruby script is in `lib/` folder. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: if you call `gem env` from your PHP script and then from the terminal, does `GEM PATH` differ? You can also use `gem which watir-webdriver` in both contexts to see where it's looking.

Comment: @meatspace, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a725ccd8278ed949040b5532b774d9b4